# Reading data from list with inconsequential whitespacing

Tags: python, split, nested-loops, nested-lists, strip

I'm a rookie who practicing, how to be better at reading data from files amongst other things.

I'm trying to extract temperature data from a file where the number of spaces between the data elements in the file is inconsequential.

The file in question looks like this:

```
Year: 1975. Month: November.
10.2   3.2  4.6 12.7 8.9  9.1    10.11
9.4    2.8 10.9  10.7   17.3    2.2    9.6
11.5  6.0 7.4   6.5    10.3 4.5    3.2
4.1  6.7 8.5    6.2    9.9   5.6    3.1
2.3   1.1  14.1
```

And I would like to append the data into a nested list where every row is a list within a list like this:

```
[[10.2, 3.2, 4.6, 12.7, 8.9, 9.1, 10.11], [9.4, 2.8, 10.9, 10.7, 17.3, 2.2, 9.6],...,[2.3, 1.1, 14.1]]
```

Now I know the solution probably involves using nested for-loops, but I'm still in the process of getting more comfortable with them. I have tried a bunch of different types of nested for loops, but none of them seems to give me the result I want.

The closest I've come to a solution is with the following code:

```
list = []

with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        line.strip().split("\n")
        list.append(line)

print(list)
```

which outputs the following:

which clearly is not what I want.

```
['10.2   3.2  4.6 12.7 8.9  9.1    10.11\n', '9.4    2.8 10.9  10.7   17.3    2.2    9.6\n', (..)', '2.3   1.1  14.1']
```

If there is someone out there who can help me solve this problem and advance my learning on this topic, I would be very grateful.

Comment: `split` returns a list. You should use this.

Comment: By default, `string.split()` splits by any amount of whitespace, functionally equivalent to `re.split(" +", str)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Michael Butscher mentioned, just use `split()`:

```
list = []

with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
    file.readline()
    for line in file:
        row = line.split()
        # convert string list to float list
        row = [float(value) for value in row]
        list.append(row)

print(list)
```

#### Output

```
[[10.2, 3.2, 4.6, 12.7, 8.9, 9.1, 10.11], [9.4, 2.8, 10.9, 10.7, 17.3, 2.2, 9.6], [11.5, 6.0, 7.4, 6.5, 10.3, 4.5, 3.2], [4.1, 6.7, 8.5, 6.2, 9.9, 5.6, 3.1], [2.3, 1.1, 14.1]]
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a nice solution. It has been very helpful:-)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
my_list = []

with open(r"filename.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file.readlines()[1:]:  # skip first line
        my_list.append([float(i) for i in line.strip().split()])

print(my_list)
[[10.2, 3.2, 4.6, 12.7, 8.9, 9.1, 10.11], [9.4, 2.8, 10.9, 10.7, 17.3, 2.2, 9.6], [11.5, 6.0, 7.4, 6.5, 10.3, 4.5, 3.2], [4.1, 6.7, 8.5, 6.2, 9.9, 5.6, 3.1], [2.3, 1.1, 14.1]]
```

Comment: Thank you for an alternative solution! The more solutions the merrier for learning!

Answer (score 1):

Neither `strip` nor `split` mutates its arguments "in-place". (strings are immutable so strip can't do anyway. and `split` returns a list out of string so that won't do also). So if you assign to their result it is fine. Also we map the contents to floats because they come as strings

```
res = []
with open("filename.txt") as file:
    # skip the very first line
    file.readline()
    # for each line...
    for line in file:
        # strip & split you did; also mapping to floats
        sub_list = [*map(float, line.rstrip("\n").split())]
        # storing in
        res.append(sub_list)

> res
[[10.2, 3.2, 4.6, 12.7, 8.9, 9.1, 10.11],
 [9.4, 2.8, 10.9, 10.7, 17.3, 2.2, 9.6],
 [11.5, 6.0, 7.4, 6.5, 10.3, 4.5, 3.2],
 [4.1, 6.7, 8.5, 6.2, 9.9, 5.6, 3.1],
 [2.3, 1.1, 14.1]]
```

note: i use `rstrip("\n")` to specifically right strip the newline at the end. (we can also do `line[:-1]` there.) Also using `split()` witohut arguments to split over any whitespace. As you do, it tries to split over newlines but there cannot be newlines in a line (especially after you strip it)!

finally! using `list` as varible name is not good! it shadows the builtin `list` of Python... So I use `res` for "result" :)

Comment: Thank you for a very elaborate and informative answer, and thank you for providing another interesting solution! It is very helpful for my learning :-)